# Error Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected in Command: joke

Tags: c#

My code is getting this error: Error Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected in Command: joke.

I am trying to choose something random from a list. This is running through a Skype bot program, but each command is a different script.
Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Skyper;
using SKYPE4COMLib;
using System.Net;

namespace Skyper.plugins
{

    public static class Help
    {

        public static string Description
        {
            get 
            {
                return "Random Object Test";
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Execute(string[] Params, int chat, string username)
    {

        List = new List("Pie1", "Pie2");
        Dim rnd as new Random();
        Dim randomFruit = List(rnd.Next(0, List1.Count));
        Skyper.SendMessage(chat, randomFruit);
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why did you tag the question with VB.NET? It's clearly C# code. Are you sure you know what you're doing? It's OK not to know the language details while you're learning how to use it, but you should at least know what language you're trying to use...

Comment: I don't see anything in the posted code that relates to the reported error: `Error Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected in Command: joke.`.  Where in the posted code is that error occurring?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - `Dim` is VB.NET, and OP is accessing `List` using VB.NET-like accessors (assuming it's a collection, that is).   I think OP is a tad bit confused at this point....

Comment: its that new VB# language

Answer (score 0):

Move the Execute method inside the class

```
namespace Skyper.plugins
{
    public static class Help
    {
        public static string Description
        {
            get 
            {
                return "Random Object Test";
            }
        }
        public static void Execute(string[] Params, int chat, string username)
        {
            List<string> List1 = new List<string>() {"Pie1", "Pie2"};
            Random rnd = new Random();
            string randomFruit = List1[rnd.Next(0, List1.Count)];
            Skyper.SendMessage(chat, randomFruit);
        }
    }
}
```

You cannot have methods outside a class definition, also there is an excess of closing curly braces.

Moreover these lines make little sense:

```
List = new List("Pie1", "Pie2");
Dim randomFruit = List(rnd.Next(0, List1.Count));
```

probably you mean

```
List<string> List1 = new List<string>() {"Pie1", "Pie2"};
string randomFruit = List1[rnd.Next(0, List1.Count)];
```

Comment: Please write here the error text, do not post links to external sites that requires custom software to see images....

Comment: Error The type or namespace name 'Dim' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) in Command: joke

Comment: It is C#, Dim is a VB.NET keyword

Comment: Error Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' requires 1 type arguments in Command: joke

Comment: Error The type or namespace name 'Dim' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) in Command: joke
Error Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' requires 1 type arguments in Command: joke
Error The name 'rnd' does not exist in the current context in Command: joke